# Unable to communicate between viewControllers of different projects inside a workspace in XCode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-workspace

I have three project A, B, C inside an workspace in XCode.
Want to call class B and C (ProjectMain in image) from A.
But it shows error "Use of unresolved identifier 'BViewController'"[image]

Comment: If your worksapce contains A.B,C then just select target mebership checkbox

Comment: Did you add the other projects in your Build Phase?

Comment: i have tried to add path of B and C in header path project A . But it not worked. adding projects to build phases means ?

Comment: Got no any solution using workspace..finally used the framework way..(Y)